# Insert statement on Hive using Oozie never ends

Tags: hive, oozie, impala, flume-twitter, oozie-workflow

im new with cloudera...., Im already working with oozie, flume, hive and impala...., I have a process that manually works as I want. I've wanted to improve the functionality using oozie for to optimize processes. Flume, is not there cause Flume doesn't need scheduling and just using oozie for hive and impala.
When data is coming to Hive..., the idea is copy the information to another table that support parquet format and read it on Impala....
Im trying to overwrite the information from a table to another, manually it works perfectly, but when I do

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_impala SELECT * FROM table_hive
```

oozie never ends the workflow and always stay on 50%...... I copied the hive-site.xml to the HDFS path and added to the xml.

```
2017-11-24 07:05:43,184 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2017-11-24 07:05:43,185 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2017-11-24 07:05:43,185 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2017-11-24 07:05:43,256 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.WorkflowNotificationXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@:start:
2017-11-24 07:05:43,256 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.WorkflowNotificationXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W
2017-11-24 07:05:43,294 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7] Start action [0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2017-11-24 07:05:46,435 INFO org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.Hive2ActionExecutor: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7] checking action, hadoop job ID [job_1511505168592_0020] status [RUNNING]
2017-11-24 07:05:46,442 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7] [***0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7***]Action status=RUNNING
2017-11-24 07:05:46,443 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7] [***0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7***]Action updated in DB!
2017-11-24 07:05:46,470 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.WorkflowNotificationXCommand: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000068-171123082943192-oozie-oozi-W@hive-8ab7
```

Comment: Did your oozie job went into "Running' state and is stuck in Running stage at 50%. Share or Check the oozie logs that is getting generated from HUE-Oozie Workflow section.